# How to save an ArrayList<File> to a file in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app which uses an ArrayList of type File.
I want to save it to a file and read it back again..any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: save the file paths instead of saving `File` objects

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList and File both implement Serializable.

So to write to file

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("myFiles.txt"));             
ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
o.writeObject(myArrayListOfFiles);
o.close();
f.close();
```

And then to read from file

```
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(new File("myFiles.txt"));          
ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
ArrayList<File> myArrayListOfFiles = (ArrayList<File>) oi.readObject();     
oi.close();
fi.close();
```

Then to make this code android specific
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

You could also write to a string instead of a file and save it in SharedPreferences with something like this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(myArrayListOfFiles);
oos.close();
String out = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
```

And reading it back in with

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(myString, Base64.DEFAULT);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
ArrayList<File> o = (ArrayList<File>) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

Comment: If my answer is what you wanted, you should mark it as accepted so people know your post does not require further attention